# How to make a login div ease in and bounce like this?

Tags: css, animation

The login box flies from the top and the input fields animate with it until the bounce is over.  It looks very cool to me.

I want to know how to make an effect like this. I think it's CSS3 animation. Is there any plugin or library for this?

http://themeforest.net/item/katniss-premium-admin-template/full_screen_preview/3878281

Comment: Well, it's easy, you should try it first, if you got stuck, than put your code here and we will help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `animation: bounceY 0.9s linear;` if your looking for a quick solution.

Or

You can use a custom cubic bezier transition like this:

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(.21,-1,.48,2);
        transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(.21,-1,.48,2);
```

Demo here <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agconti/NvJMd/3/)</kbd>. Just hover over the back div.

You can change and adjust the effect until you get it just right!

Answer (score 0):

try using something like  [jQuery Easing Plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/). i use it almost in my project and it has a lot of functionality, i hope this will help you.